# laravel 5 hash check and redirect not working

Tags: php, laravel, hash

In a quite strange situation, I am trying to Hash::Check my password from database and user input, however it work.

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->username)->get()->first();       

if(Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
    return Redirect::to('secondpage')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Strangely, if I change my password in database to plain text and use Hash::check with it, it works.
Any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the hash check or the redirect that doesn't work? Anyways you don't implement any session mechanism (it could be a smarter idea if you want keep the user logged)

Comment: Put the passwords examples please (encrypted and not encrypted). To check if a problem with hash or another approach

Comment: Hey Pedro, I'm using encrypted password in my database and request contains plain password from form.

Comment: This is the encrypted password i stored for "123456"
$2y$10$6Bt/T8pcmuY9sK2xd6nJKOyEPUnN6bVXYHWSCxaF2M19Y5jt846Ty

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but there might be a typo in your code, you might want to fetch your user like so :

```
$user = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();
```